# How to correctly check for a sub-attribute returned by a function in Javascript/MeteorJS

Tags: javascript, meteor

In my code, I was checking `if (Meteor.user().profile.something.someAttribute) {`. However, this throws a TypeError if the Meteor user is not logged in (i.e., calling `Meteor.user()` fails). I would think that this would fail more elegantly, since the if statement would see that and then not execute. However, it throws the error and then screws up my application. I fixed it by doing

```
if(Meteor.user()) {
  if (Meteor.user().profile.something.someAttribute) {
```

but this doesn't seem very elegant. Is there a better way to do this, or do I have some fundamental misunderstanding of Javascript?

Answer (score 2):

When the user is not logged in, `Meteor.user()` returns `null`, as [stated in the documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_user) and trying to access `profile` of `null` fails. Checking the return value is the only way to do it, but you can write it a little more elegantly:

```
let user = Meteor.user();
if (user && user.profile.something.someAttribute) { … }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is really more of a javascript question than a meteor question. It's also a very common pattern. You might find this solution slightly more elegant:

```
if (Meteor.user() 
    && Meteor.user().profile.something.someAttribute) {
```

But there is no real way around this unless you want to write a helper function, which you could, for instance:

```
function check(object) {
    if (argument.length == 0) {
        return object;
    } else if (object) {
        return check(object[arguments[0]], arguments.slice(1));
    } else {
        return undefined;
    }
}
```

and then use

```
if (check(Meteor.user(), "profile", "something", "someAttribute")) {
```

this will proceed with care and check for undefined for each sub-object before asking for sub-subs.